# ListView does not work as a child of Column or Row

Tags: flutter, dart

I`m new in flutter framework and I want to use CustomLists.
My (body:) I wants to add a listviewBuilder into a Column but I give an empty page. if I use only listView in body part every things is fine.

Here is my Widget:

```
Widget _buildListView() {
    return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Dismissible(
        key: Key('ke'),
        onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
          if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
            print('Swiped end to start');
          } else if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
            print('Swiped start to end');
          } else {
            print('Other swiping');
          }
        },
        background: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        child: Container(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 2.0),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text('12'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 8.0,
                        ),
                        Text('135'),
                      ],
                    )
                  ]),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              width: 15,
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 5,
                            ),
                            Text('120'),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 5,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.yellow,
                              width: 15,
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ]),
                ),
                Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                      Text('30'),
                    ])),
              ],
            ),
            Divider()
          ],
        )),
      );
    },itemCount: 10,);
  }
```

I get this errors:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():

I/flutter (14466): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

I/flutter (14466): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical

I/flutter (14466): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation

I/flutter (14466): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.

I/flutter (14466): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because

I/flutter (14466): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column

I/flutter (14466): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size

I/flutter (14466): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
```

Comment: Why are you using `Column` inside `ListView`?

Comment: Remove the outer container and try again. If you are using a column then you don't need that Outer Container. A container can only hold one widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `shrinkWrap` property `true` for listview.

```
ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap:true,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
 return Container();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to wrap your `ListView` in a container that has the specified `width` and `height` values.

for example, wrap the `ListView` in the `Container` with height and with values or wrap it to an `Expanded` widget to fill the entire space its parent.

```
Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: ListView.builder() // your list view builder widget
)
```

or

```
Expanded(
   child: ListView.builder() // your list view builder widget
)
```

note that you should use the `Expanded` widget inside a flex widget that has specified the width and height values. like `Column`, `Row` , ...

Also, you should set the `shrinkWrap` value to `true` when using `ListView` inside another `ListView` widget.